# How to call an angular controller function from within an iframe

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe

I am using an iframe for processing 3D authentication for credit card payments within a multi-step shop checkout form that uses Angular.

After authentication has been completed, I need to call a function to proceed to the next step, from within the iframe. The iframe is on the same domain as the parent window. However, I get a `scope.showStep is not a function` error when calling the function.

How can I achieve this?

Iframe content:

```
<script>
    var scope = parent.angular.element(parent.document.getElementById("checkout-form")).scope();
    scope.$apply(function () {
        scope.showStep('success!')
    });
</script>
```

Checkout controller:

```
(function () {
    angular
        .module('app.checkout')
        .controller('CheckoutStep', CheckoutStep);

    CheckoutStep.$inject = ['$scope', '$state'];

    function CheckoutStep($scope, $state) {

        $scope.showStep = function (message) {
            $state.go('checkout.step', { message: message });
        }
    }
})();
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app.checkout" id="checkout-form">
    <div ui-view id="checkout-step></div>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="checkout-step1">
        // template
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: i would suggest using `postMessage`  for cross frame communication.

Comment: I've added clarification - the iframe and parent are on the same domain, so I didn't think postMessage was necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code was actually working correctly, however I was fetching the wrong element from the page. Instead of the app element, I needed to retrieve the view element, since I am using UI router.

**Note that `scope()` is not accessible if `debugInfoEnabled` is set to false.**

```
<script>
    var scope = parent.angular.element(parent.document.getElementById("checkout-step")).controller ();
    scope.$apply(function () {
        scope.showStep('success!')
    });
</script>
```

Comment: var controller should be var scope